# .NumberFormat VBA function Chr escape sequence

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

```
Dim HKD As String

HKD = "K[$$-409] #,##0.00;[Red]-(K[$$-409] #,##0.00)"
Range("CurrencyFormat_FF_ResourceTable").NumberFormat = HKD
```

CurrencyFormat_FF_ResourceTable = K$ 0.00

```
HKD = "HK[$$-409] #,##0.00;[Red]-(HK[$$-409] #,##0.00)" 
Range("CurrencyFormat_FF_ResourceTable").NumberFormat = HKD
```

CurrencyFormat_FF_ResourceTable = old values

wanting CurrencyFormat_FF_ResourceTable = HK$ 0.00

Comment: Can you share some sample values that are in the "CurrencyFormat_FF_ResourceTable" range?

Comment: I am trying to have cells that will have the type of currency with the symbol HK$ instead of $. More context will probably not help you. I am trying to use symbols that are incompatible with the.NumberFormat function. Is there an escape sequence? so values in the resource table will default to $HK 0.00 and will update depending on formula inputs.

Comment: I was getting at not explaining a way to test the output of format. i.e. you want want negative values to be red but it's fine. When posting I prefer to not assume everyone intuitively understands the acceptance criteria so everyone who is helping is sure they can test the answer. ***Anyway***, in your post you have a typo so not sure if this exists in the actual code as well. You have both `HKD` & `HDK`. If typo does actually exist in your code then you should add `Option Explicit` in the future which will flag your typos as undeclared variables i.e. raising an compile error on the 2nd line

Comment: Sorry about the typo it was in the question not the code

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the literal text in quotes:

```
HKD = """HK""[$$-409] #,##0.00;[Red]-(""HK""[$$-409] #,##0.00)"
```